# SFTP to chroot and SSH to manage system in one config?

Tags: sftp, chroot, ssh

We have a webserver where users are allowed to upload (SFTP) large files in a chroot environment. We also want to be able to use SSH to manage this server.

In our old situation we used the system sshd and a chroot environment with a seperate sshd running inside. I hoped I could simplify the configuration with the 'new' ChrootDirectory option.

Our server has two IP addresses, one for public access and one for internal access. Is it possible for a single sshd to listen to two seperate IPs/interfaces but treat them differently? In all the documentation I have read it seems like it is only possible to distinguish between users or groups, but not IPs/interfaces.

If this is not possible, is the dual sshd setup the best option, should I do beter User Management to filter them by Group or is there a more elegant way to setup a server like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Match` in a reverse way. Chroot by default and then negate the directive if connecting from the internal network.

```
ChrootDirectory /chroot/somedir
Match Address 10.0.0.0/24
    ChrootDirectory none
```

However you should consider the implications of placing security decisions upon the networks. Including the possibility of an authenticated user creating a new session over loopback, to bypass such policies. Generally it would be safer to define `User` and `Group` if possible.

*(edit: typed before reading properly)*

Answer (score 2):

The solution that I used in the end is the following:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
ChrootDirectory <my chroot directory>
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp

Match User <my admin account> Address <my ip>
  ChrootDirectory none
  X11Forwarding yes
  AllowTcpForwarding yes
  ForceCommand /bin/bash

Match User <my admin account>
  ForceCommand none
```

So it is a mix of the answers I saw before, and I made two Match blocks, so that people from other IPs, but trying to use my admin account won't be able to use sftp or ssh. I will be monitoring the activity on the server closely to see if this works out, but internal tests look promising.

Answer (score 1):

I created a group called sftpuplod. Every customer without ssh-access is in this group an just can use sftp:

```
# sshd_config:
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group sftpupload
    ChrootDirectory /home
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

You also can use **ChrootDirectory %h** for real chrooting in ~

see the [manual page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config)